# Android display item inside dropdown list

Tags: android, adapter, selection, display

I have a TextInputLayout with style ExposedDropdownMenu. this TextInputLayout contains an AutoCompleteTextView.
I can add a list item inside this AutoCompleteTextView using an adapter.

```
        mLightSensorGainTextInput = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.paramLightSensorGain);
        String[] gainStrArray = new String[] {"1", "2"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> gainAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.version_list_item, gainStrArray);
        mLightSensorGainTextInput.setAdapter(gainAdapter);
```

I would like to set one value displayed when I click a "setDefaultButton" but I have always the initial view:
[image]

I tried :

```
mLightSensorGainTextInput.setListSelection(0);
mLightSensorGainTextInput.setSelection(0);
```

but none of the 2 methods shows the value expected which is : 1.
Do you have any suggestion?
Best regards
Mich

Please here is more informations about what I expect. Only last operation (default button) does not work.
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? Are you trying to set something else as defult value? And that is not at 0th position in adapter, is it?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I added more informations here above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the filter:

```
mLightSensorGainTextInput.setText("1", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `setText()`:

```
mLightSensorGainTextInput.setText("xxx");
```

Comment: Thanks Sam but in this case it delete the choice "2"

Comment: @Mich After `setText()`, set the adapter again.

Answer (score 0):

As your items are text-based, you can get the first item from the adapter by `autoCompleteTextView.getAdapter().getItem(position)`; then to make it the current selection; set the text of the `autoCompleteTextView` to that item: `mLightSensorGainTextInput.setText((mLightSensorGainTextInput.getAdapter().getItem(0)).toString());`

Comment: Thanks Zain but same result than Sam: this delete the choice 2 afterwards